# boost::timer::cpu_timer shows no elapsed time under mingw64

Tags: boost, mingw, cpu-usage

I was noticing this in my own code, and decided to verify it using the example code that comes with Boost.timer.  Maybe it doesn't work with the tdm64 compiler?

Here are the results:

```
% g++ --version
g++.exe (tdm64-1) 4.6.1
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

% 
% g++ -Wall -ggdb3 -o auto_cpu_timer_example boost_1_49_0/libs/timer/example/auto_cpu_timer_example.cpp -lboost_timer -lboost_chrono -lboost_system
% 
% g++ -Wall -ggdb3 -o timex boost_1_49_0/libs/timer/example/timex.cpp  -lboost_timer -lboost_chrono -lboost_system
%
% auto_cpu_timer_example.exe 
 0.000000s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (0.0%)
%
%
% ./timex -v auto_cpu_timer_example.exe 
 0.000000s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (0.0%)
command: "auto_cpu_timer_example.exe"
 0.000000s elapsed wall-clock time
%
```

Answer (score 0):

The example code is broken:

```
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
  boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t;

  for (long i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    std::sqrt(123.456L); // burn some time

  return 0;
}
```

The `std::sqrt` function is a pure function. That is, it has no effects other than to return a value based solely on its parameter. If that value isn't used, the function invocation can be discarded. Since the return value isn't used, the function can be skipped. This results in the code using no time at all.

You can fix it this way:

```
  long t = 0;
  for (long i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    t += std::sqrt(123.456L + i); // burn some time
  std::cout << "t = " << t << std::endl;
```

Now, the return value is used and the parameter is different every time. This means the function *will* be invoked repeatedly, giving you something to time.

Comment: Okay, I agree that there is a problem with the example, but fixing the example doesn't fix the underlying problem I'm having with boost::auto_cpu_timer

    ./auto_cpu_timer_example.exe 
    res = 946627714
     0.000000s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (0.0%)

Comment: Now it looks like your platform is broken.

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering if this is an issue with the TDM64 compiler, or maybe I had a bad configuration for building the boost library with TDM64...

Comment: Sorry for the 6 year late response but I do appreciate this explanation.  Unfortunately my up-votes don't count for much.